# A simple C program output is not as expected

Tags: c

I was doing this simple program and my mind got stuck

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        signed int a;
        signed char c;
        unsigned char b;
        b = 0xf4;
        a = (signed)b;       //    1)this assignment should be same 
        c = (signed)b;
        printf("%d\n",a);
        a = c;              //     2)as this one
        printf("%d \n",a);
        return 0; 
    }

a = 244, a = -12
```

I tried to make sure that assignment is as smooth as it can be but I am getting two different answers and I expected both as -12. What small thing I am missing?

---

The relevant question was

```
{
    b = 0xf4;
    c = 0xf4;
    a = (signed int)b;           //trying to save sign but get 244 
    printf("%d\n", a);
    a = c;                       //sign saved here and got -3 
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

244, -3

so i am trying to save the sign from an unsigned char. Is this possible in this manner?

Comment: Your compiler is seriously broken if you get -3 - it should be -12: http://ideone.com/kgBTUS

Comment: I guess it's because of the type conversion char-int.

Comment: I'm not a C rockstar. I think casting in `(signed)` both `int` and `char` is wrong. It should be `(signed int)` and `(signed char)`

Comment: @Glenn I would have said the same thing. `signed` is as far as I know the same type as `int`. So he is casting it to int and saving it in a char.

Comment: @mrigendra: Editing the question to be more correct after someone told you an error, and staying silent about it, is not ok ... what´s the point in the answer/comment then?

Comment: This is relying on integer overflow, and is thus technically undefined behaviour.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth no undefined behavior here, implementation defined integer conversion to a narrower signed type as ruled by 6.3.1.3p3 in c99.

Comment: @ouah: yup, you are correct.

Comment: @TimSeguine You're both correct. `signed` cast is equivalent to `signed int`. The former of the two, `a = (signed)b;` is valid and fully supported through integer promotions and value-conversion. The latter is implementation defined only.

Comment: @WhozCraig it doesn't really seem to have an effect. I am guessing because one fits in the target type and the other doesn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    signed char c;
    unsigned char b;
    b = 0xf4;

    /* ... */

    c = (signed)b;
```

The value of `b` is `0xf4` (`244`) but `c` type (`signed char`) can only hold values between `-128` and `127` (in your implementation). So when `244` is assigned to `c` it is first converted to `signed char` and C says this integer conversion is implementation defined. `gcc` as most implementations 
just wraps around modulo `256` and that's why the value of `c`  is `-12`.

Here is `gcc` documentation:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html

> "For conversion to a type of width N, the value is reduced modulo 2^N to be within range of the type"

Comment: so overall c is getting an int value and that value's 8 bits are stored ,so it becomes -12

Comment: I have edited the que to put the real issue forward.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is located here:

```
c = (signed)b;
```

casting the value of b, 244, to a signed char leads to an integer overflow, resulting in the value of -12 that you see. Changing the type of c to `signed int` solves the issue.

Comment: You will get same results even if you do not typecast

Comment: @Vagish Even without a cast, the value is **converted** to the type of `c` on assignment. This answer is using the word “cast” incorrectly to refer to the conversion on assignment.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to say,It is not a problem it is expected behavior.I always load 0xff to signed char to interpret as '-1'

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the output of `244` is correct. First, `b` is initialized to a value of `244` expressed as as a hexadecimal literal, which is then cast to the `signed int a`, which can hold the value of `244`. According to the specification of [printf format strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), the output of `244` is what is to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

Event if You do not typecast 'b' by signed you will get same results.

In first assignment

a = (signed)b;

you are loading a signed int(16bit/32bit/64bit) with 0xf4 which it can hold,and as msb is '0' the result will be 244.

If your int would have been 8 bits long then the result will be '-12'.

In second case you must get '-12' because 2's complement of '-12' is 0xf4.