# Cyclic Nature of char datatype

Tags: c

I had been learning C and came across topic called Cyclic Nature of Data Type in C.

It is like example

```
char c=125;
c=c+10;
printf("%d",c);
```

The output is -121. 
  the logic given was

```
125+1= 126
125+2= 127
125+3=-128
125+4=-127
125+5=-126
125+6=-125
125+7=-124
125+8=-123
125+9=-122
125+10=-121
```

This is due to cyclic nature if char datatype. Y does Char exhibit cyclic nature?? How is it possible to char??

Comment: I don't know about Cyclic Nature of Data Type thing that you mentioned. The explanation to what you describe is called overflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your system `char` is `signed char`. When a signed integral type overflows, the result is undefined. It may or may not be cyclic. Although on most of the machines performing 2's complement arithmetic, you may observe this as cyclic.

Comment: I know that its an overflow but the topic is explained as Cyclic Nature of Data type

Comment: @shashank then you should either throw away hard or burn the book you are reading.

Comment: @shashank Don't read the tutorial

Comment: Thank you i finally got clarity not to believe something blindly

Comment: The operands of `+` are promoted to `int` (so the addition doesn't overflow). The conversion back to `char` is _implementation-defined_ (or an implementation-defined signal is raised) and I guess most compilers define it like gcc, where the conversion is as shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `char` data type is `signed` type, as per your implementation. As such it can store values in range: `-128 to 127`. When you store a value greater than 127, you would end up with a value that might be in negative or positive number, depending on how large is the value stored and what kind of platform you are  working on.
Signed integer overflow is `undefined` behavior in C and then not at all unsigned numbers are guaranteed to wrap around.

Comment: char type may be signed or unsigned (implementation dependent) and minimum range of signed char is `-127 to 127` which is `-128 to 127` on most of the system working in 2s complement system.

Comment: @MohitJain The char data type is implementation defined, but as per OP's question and code output, its clear that its signed in his platform. Still updated the answer to reflect this construct.

Comment: (+1) This is much clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

`char` isn’t special in this regard (besides its implementation-defined signedness), all conversions to signed types usually exhibit this “cyclic nature”. However, there are undefined and implementation-defined aspects of signed overflow, so be careful when doing such things.

What happens here:

In the expression

```
c=c+10
```

the operands of `+` are subject to the *usual arithmetic conversions*. They include *integer promotion*, which converts all values to `int` if all values of their type can be represented as an `int`. This means, the left operand of `+` (`c`) is converted to an `int` (an `int` can hold every `char` value<sup>1)</sup>). The result of the addition has type `int`. The assignment implicitly converts this value to a `char`, which happens to be signed on your platform. An (8-bit) signed `char` cannot hold the value 135 so it is converted in an implementation-defined way <sup>2)</sup>. For [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation):

> For conversion to a type of width **N**, the value is reduced modulo **2<sup>N</sup>** to be within range of the type; no signal is raised.

Your `char` has a width of **8**, **2<sup>8</sup>** is **256**, and **135 ☰ -121 mod 256** (cf. e.g. [2’s complement on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)).

You didn’t say which compiler you use, but the behaviour should be the same for all compilers (there aren’t really any non-2’s-complement machines anymore and with 2’s complement, that’s the only reasonable signed conversion definition I can think of).

Note, that this implementation-defined behaviour only applies to conversions, not to overflows in arbitrary expressions, so e.g.

```
int n = INT_MAX;
n += 1;
```

is undefined behaviour and used for optimizations by some compilers (e.g. by optimizing such statements out), so such things should definitely be avoided.

A third case (unrelated here, but for sake of completeness) are unsigned integer types: No overflow occurs (there are exceptions, however, e.g. bit-shifting by more than the width of the type), the result is always reduced modulo **2<sup>N</sup>** for a type with precision **N**.

Related:

- [A simple C program output is not as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156897/a-simple-c-program-output-is-not-as-expected)
- [Allowing signed integer overflows in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240748/allowing-signed-integer-overflows-in-c-c)

---

<sup>1</sup> At least for 8-bit `char`s, signed `char`s, or `int`s with higher precision than `char`, so virtually always.

<sup>2</sup> The C standard says (C99 and C11 (n1570) 6.3.1.3 p.3) “[…] either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.” I don’t know of any implementation raising a signal in this case. But it’s probably better not to rely on that conversion without reading the compiler documentation.